# Water is poured in a glass at a rate of $1.9$ cm$^3$ /s. How fast does the liquid level rise when the liquid height in the glass is $7.0$ cm?

Tags: calculus, volume

Water is poured in a glass at a rate of $1.9~\text{cm}^3/\text{s}$. How fast does the liquid level rise when the liquid height in the glass is $7.0~\text{cm}$?

[image: cone_diagram]

I have used uniformity on the triangle to get a second triangle and got it to $7*7$ Not sure how to think to find the equation I need to solve.

Comment: Hi, @Maria, welcome to math.stackexchange. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Here is a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  We know that the volume of a cone is $V = \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$.  We wish to express the volume as a function of its height, then differentiate implicitly with respect to time.  Can you express the radius $r$ at height $h$ as a function of $h$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig $r=squareroot(3V/hπ) You mean like this?

Comment: No.  I meant you should write $r$ as a function of $h$.  I have written an answer which should clarify the matter.

Comment: It might be worth clearly separating out your question from your evidence of what you have tried, as some users have a habit of downvoting reasonable questions because the evidence you gave of what you tried, demonstrated a flawed attempt.  That said, this is a cone, not a triangle so the rate of filling up is inversely is proportional to the SQUARE of the radius, rather than the diameter itself.

Answer (score 3):

We wish to find $\frac{dh}{dt}$, the rate at which the height is changing with respect to time.  The volume of a cone is 
$$V = \frac{1}{3}\pi r^2h$$
In order to find $\frac{dh}{dt}$, we need to write $V$ as a function of $h$, then differentiate the resulting equation with respect to time, so we must eliminate $r$.  To do so, we must express $r$ in terms of $h$.

Consider the diagram below:

[image: diagram_of_cone]

Since the diameter of the cone is $18~\text{cm}$, its radius is $9~\text{cm}$.  By similar triangles,
$$\frac{r}{h} = \frac{9~\text{cm}}{18~\text{cm}} = \frac{1}{2} \implies r = \frac{h}{2}$$
Substituting for $r$ in the equation for the volume gives 
$$V = \frac{1}{3}\pi\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)^2h = \frac{1}{12}\pi h^3$$
Differentiating both sides of the equation implicitly with respect to time yields 
$$\frac{dV}{dt} = \frac{1}{4}\pi h^2\frac{dh}{dt}$$
Solving for $\frac{dh}{dt}$ gives
$$\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{4}{\pi h^2}\frac{dV}{dt}$$
Now, you just need to substitute the given numbers to complete the problem.

Comment: [+1] Wonderful graphic! This will be useful for present and future students.